# Attempt to read property "id" on null laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Can someone help me?
I have an error Attempt to read property "id" on null Laravel 8 while trying to show my table

**Migration Tables**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username', 20)->unique();
            $table->string('password', 20);
            $table->enum('level',['admin', 'manager', 'pegawai']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('id_user')
                ->constrained('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('nama_pgw', 50);
            $table->string('alamat');
            $table->string('no_telp', 13);
            $table->string('email', 30)->unique;
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

**Employee Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'employees';
    protected $fillable = ['nama_pgw', 'username', 'alamat', 'no_telp', 'email'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::class); 
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'level'];

    public function employee(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'id_user', 'id');
    }
}
```

**User Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $users = User::get();
        return view('user/index', compact('users'));
        
    }
}
```

**Employee Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\User;

class PegawaiController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {

        $pegawai = Employee::get();
        return view('pegawai/index', compact('pegawai'));

    }
}
```

This is my view

```
<select name="id_user" id="username" class="uk-select">
    <option>- pilih username -</option>
        @foreach ($pegawai as $emp)
           option value="{{$emp->users->id}}">{{$emp->users->nama_pgw}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Is it any problem on foreign key? I keep checking on typos possibility but everything seems right.
thank you!

Comment: you need to refactor your code, maybe some typo errors and be sure what you're trying to do on $emp->users..??? where you define this?

Comment: @Prospero the $emp defined $pegawai on my Employee Controller to users as a foreign key table.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your relation in the employee Model is "user" while you are referring to it in blade view as "users".

Also, to run your code you can update your view:

```
<select name="id_user" id="username" class="uk-select">
    <option>- pilih username -</option>
        @foreach ($pegawai as $emp)
           <option value="{{$emp->user->id}}">{{$emp->user->nama_pgw}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

**Edited:**

I will also suggest optimizing your query by using eager loading. In your current code, it will execute n+1 queries where 1 query to retrieve employees and N queries to retrieve user for each employee

Update it with below code:

```
class PegawaiController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {

        $pegawai = Employee::with(['user'])->get();
        return view('pegawai/index', compact('pegawai'));

    }
}
```

Comment: It works! I thought the "users" in blade view is referring to the table name. I still need to learn more. Thank you!

Comment: @RadenBagus Updated my answer. You can optimize it as well.